# R install package curl: "handle.c:30:1: error: unknown type name 'curl_sslbackend'"

Tags: r, curl

Oracle Linux 7, R 3.3.0

```
[oracle@ildar ~]$ yum list | grep curl
curl.x86_64                          7.29.0-54.0.1.el7       installed
libcurl.x86_64                       7.29.0-54.0.1.el7       installed
libcurl-devel.x86_64                 7.29.0-54.0.1.el7       installed
python-pycurl.x86_64                 7.19.0-19.el7           @odadom1
libcurl.i686                         7.29.0-54.0.1.el7       ol7_latest
libcurl-devel.i686                   7.29.0-54.0.1.el7       ol7_latest
[oracle@ildar ~]$
```

i.e. libcurl installed.
next try to install curl package in R:

```
[oracle@ildar ~]$ ORE CMD INSTALL curl_4.1.tar.gz
* installing to library '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/dbhome_1/R/library'
* installing *source* package 'curl' ...
** package 'curl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
** libs
rm -f curl.so callbacks.o curl.o download.o escape.o fetch.o form.o getdate.o handle.o ieproxy.o init.o interrupt.o multi.o nslookup.o reflist.o split.o ssl.o typechecking.o utils.o version.o winidn.o writer.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c callbacks.c -o callbacks.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c curl.c -o curl.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c download.c -o download.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c escape.c -o escape.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c fetch.c -o fetch.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c form.c -o form.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c getdate.c -o getdate.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG -DSTRICT_R_HEADERS -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/systemr/port/Linux-X64/include    -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c handle.c -o handle.o
handle.c:30:1: error: unknown type name 'curl_sslbackend'
 curl_sslbackend default_ssl_backend;
 ^
make: *** [handle.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'curl'
* removing '/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0.0/dbhome_1/R/library/curl'
```

no matter if I install from local file or from cloud, I get the same error

```
handle.c:30:1: error: unknown type name 'curl_sslbackend'
```

How to install curl without errors?

Answer (score 3):

I found solution.
The reason is that curl 4.1 has error.
4.0 should be installed instead:
https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/204#issuecomment-532162699

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/curl/curl_4.0.tar.gz",repo=NULL,type="source")
```